# iPad Partial Curl Modal View causes MPMoviePlayer to restart

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2, mpmovieplayer

I'm developing a presentation app for a client, and in the presentation the client is able to double tap a slide to view a "sub-slide", which means the current slide does a partial curl transition to present a full screen modal view.

My issue is that these main slides are animated videos (the sub-slides are all still images in PNG format). Whenever the user triggers the page curl, the movie either stays in its current state like it should (either still playing or paused), and when the page curl animation is complete, the movie restarts itself. This occurs regardless of the movie's state.

I tried putting NSLog messages and breakpoints in to see if a method such as viewWillDisappear was being called, but I found nothing.

Any idea what could be causing these videos to restart themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO ALL WHO ARE WONDERING:

I solved this issue by forcing the MoviePlayer to jump to the last frame and replacing it with an UIImageView instead, which allowed me to unload the movie, save space, and removed my flickering issue as images complete the transition with no problems.

Also, if you are encountering flickering as well when switching between full screen videos or full screen videos and images (png's in my case), delete/comment out this line:

```
self.mplayer.fullscreen = YES;
```

the problem will be gone after that.